# How do I select all list items in an unordered list that contain a checkbox that's checked?

Tags: jquery

I have `'ul > li'` to get all of the list items, but I need to only grab the items that contain a checkbox that's checked.

So you can see this visually, it looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to pull the 1st and 3rd item.

Thanks in advance.

So, I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a solution to your question: http://jsfiddle.net/H4qba/1/

HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />a</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"/>b</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"/>c</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"/>d</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />e</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />f</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('ul > li').has('input[checked="checked"]').css({border:'1px solid #c00'});
```

Comment: to point out that it is working, this is how hundreds of examples are done on jQuery web site too. (I don't get who down voted a working solution)

Comment: @Yatrix: Using `.css` to visually highlight in a fiddle the result is quite common. Mind you, in this specific example you would not be able to tell if it was the `input` control or the `li` that was matched.

Comment: You can thank @FrançoisWahl for the correct answer. I changed my original answer to yours. He pointed the note out here:  api.jquery.com/has-selector

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:has` selector.

```
$('ul li:has(input[type=checkbox]:checked)')
```

Comment: +1. As a side-note for OP, just in case it becomes relevant: `Because :has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").has(selector/DOMElement) instead.` as per docs: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Answer (score 5):

why not go backwards and start with checked inputs

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').parent()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N7VFc/

and if you need context in case there are other checkboxes in the page you can specify it in the selector

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked','ul li').parent()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$("ul > li input:checked").closest('li');
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/ktCT2/)